# Group by row and get sum of colums using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, sum, data-science, data-cleaning

i want to get sum of each column according to group by rows. how can i do this with pandas?
[image]

Comment: i want to get sum of each day by country

Comment: Isn't it just `df.groupby('Country').sum()`?

Comment: no it doesn't work

Comment: It should work, can you post the error or output when you tried df.groupby('Country').sum()

Comment: no i want to replace and save new csv file which taken by df.groupby('Country').sum() this

Comment: can you please give a sample of exact output you need ?

Comment: i got grouped data set by country using this df.groupby('Country').sum(). how can i save this output as csv?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved problem.
to group and download zip file :

```
from google.colab import files
compression_opts = dict(method='zip',archive_name='out.csv')  
xyz.groupby('Country/Region').sum().to_csv('out.zip', index=True,compression=compression_opts)
files.download('out.zip')
```